# Kotlin Map: validator not returning correct mappings

Tags: kotlin

I have the following state transition representation:

```
class State(private val startStatus: Status, private val expectedStatus: Status) {
   
  companion object StatusList {
    val listStatuses = listOf(
      State(Status.A, Status.B),
      State(Status.B, Status.A),
      State(Status.B, Status.C),
      State(Status.C, Status.B),
      State(Status.C, Status.E),
      State(Status.C, Status.D),
      State(Status.D, Status.B),
      State(Status.E, Status.C),
      State(Status.E, Status.B)
    )
   
    open fun mapStatuses(): Map<Status, List<Status>> {
      return listStatuses.groupBy({ it.startStatus }, { it.expectedStatus })
     // this returns {A=[B], B=[A, C], C=[B, E, D], D=[E], E=[C, B]}
    }
  }
}
```

I have written a validator that takes the initial status and return the allowed values. Although relatively straightforward, I cannot wrap around my head as why the below implementation results in some of the expected mappings to fail:

```
fun isStateChangeValid(
    startStatus: Status,
    matchingStatus: List<Status>
  ): Boolean {
 
    val statusMap = mapStatuses()
 
    return statusChangeMap.containsKey(startStatus) && statusChangeMap.containsValue(matchingStatus) ?: false 
}
```

Can you help? Where am I going horribly wrong?

**EDIT**

These are the expected mappings:

```
{A=[B], B=[A, C], C=[B, E, D], D=[E], E=[C, B]}
```

I am expecting to map the same key to multiple values when, for example, I provide the following:

```
isStateChangeValid(B,A) -> true
isStateChangeValid(B,C) -> true
```

but also this should be true as per the above:

```
isStateChangeValid(A,B) -> true
```

**EDIT 2**

I have ended up with this:

```
fun isStateChangeValid(
    startStatus: Status,
    matchingStatus: List<Status>
  ): Boolean {

for ((k, v) in statusChangeMap) {
      return if (k == startStatus && v[0] == matchingStatus[0]) {
        println("Find value by key  : $k = ${v[0]}")
        true
      } else {
        false
      }
    }
    return true ?: false
}
```

The failing cases are the following:

(B,A) (for which it exists the opposite A = [B] and it works
(B,C)
(C,E)
(C,D)
(E,C)
(E,B)

Exactly the same results with previous version of the method. Any idea?

Comment: What exactly is `matchingStatus` here?  As it stands, it must be _exactly_ equal to the complete list of matching statuses for some start status, and must be in the same order as those mappings appear in `mapStatuses`.

Comment: ```matchingStatus``` is each value per key. For example for ```B = [A,C]``, my matching status should allow a list of 1 with A and with C. I am rather confused about it. Shall I actually considering using Pairs? I must admit I am finding myself rather lost, although the concept is not that overly complicated

Comment: For which mappings does the above fail? Please provide a sample input paired with expected and actual output. And a description why the expected output is, well, expected.

Comment: The expected output is what I posted above, meaning the expected map {A=[B], B=[A, C], C=[B, E, D], D=[E], E=[C, B]}. It fails, for example, with (B,A), but works with (A,B). What I am struggling with is to understand where the validator is intrinsically wrong

Comment: I have now updated the question with some additional info

Comment: Your `isStateChangeValid` takes a `Status` and a `List<Status>`. It cannot be called (even in simplification) like `isStateChangeValid(A,B)`, but you do that in your example. Why do you need a list, then? This is still somewhat unclear. In addition, you are always `return`ing in your `for()` loop, meaning that it's useless. A decent IDE should warn you about that.

Comment: I need to validate all possible matches as per the map posted in the question. Are you saying that I should be simply have the second argument (expected value) as Status instead of list of statuses?

Comment: No, I never suggested that. I suggested that you should inspect the warnings of your IDE and use a debugger to see where does the logic fail. But, in fact, it would be nice to hear why it's a list of `Status`es, not just a `Status`. Just explain (in your own words, but be specific) what should `isStateChangeValid` do. Should it check whether a change from **one** `Status` to **one another** `Status` is valid, according to `mapStatuses()` return value? If yes, then why does it take a list as a second argument?

Comment: Say, wouldn't this be sufficient enoguh: `fun isStateChangeValid(startStatus: Status, matchingStatus: Status): Boolean { return State.mapStatuses()[startStatus]?.contains(matchingStatus) ?: false }` ? Notice the change in the parameter. Now you can check whether `isStateChangeValid(Status.B, Status.A)`, and it returns `true`.